# What is php's include order?

Tags: php, include

Based on PHP's documentation I would've expected that the following file hierarchy

```
.
├── autoload.php
└── etc
    └── php-lib
        ├── autoload.php
        └── common.php

2 directories, 3 files
```

And following contents:

```
cat autoload.php 
<?php
echo "I am the wrong autoloader";

cat etc/php-lib/autoload.php 
<?php
echo "This is the right one!";

cat etc/php-lib/common.php  
<?php

include_once('autoload.php');
```

That when I run

```
$ php etc/php-lib/common.php
```

That I would get following output:

```
This is the right one!
```

I expect this because the manual states that:

```
Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the
include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the include_path, 
include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the 
current working directory before failing. The include construct will emit 
a warning if it cannot find a file; this is different behavior from 
require, which will emit a fatal error.
```

However, I get this:

```
I am the wrong autoloader
```

So why is `autoload.php` loaded instead of `etc/php-lib/autoload.php`?

In fact, when I strace this, the include order seems even weirder than expected based on the manual:

First case, all files as depicted above exist

```
getcwd("/home/hvdb/temp2", 4096)        = 17
lstat("/home/hvdb/temp2/./autoload.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=40, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home/hvdb/temp2/autoload.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=40, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/hvdb/temp2/autoload.php", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

We see that  PHP first looks for the `autoload.php` in the cwd.

If I delete that file, i.e., `./autoload.php` I get the following:

```
getcwd("/home/hvdb/temp2", 4096)        = 17
lstat("/home/hvdb/temp2/./autoload.php", 0x7fff7f04e880) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("/usr/share/php/autoload.php", 0x7fff7f04e880) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("/home/hvdb/temp2/etc/php-lib/autoload.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=38, ...}) = 0
```

Only then I see PHP (still first checking for the `autoload.php` in the cwd) for the directories set in the include_directories and afterwards for the `autoloader.php` in the directory of the call script.

So, is the documentation wrong, or am I misinterpreting the manual?

Comment: your include_path starts with `.` I guess

Comment: what does `echo get_include_path()` show?

Comment: Or `php -d include_path='' etc/php-lib/common.php`

Comment: The relevant part of the documentation is `Files are included based on [...] the
include_path specified`

Comment: @ChrisLear is right. Mostly likely you've set your `include_path` in your php.ini file. I've tested your code here myself and I'm getting the right one returned without any problems.

Comment: Indeed, the '.' is the first include directory. This is a default install on ubuntu. Not sure at this point if this is just an insane default.

Comment: Apparently this is also the case for the official php docker image `docker run -ti --rm php -r 'echo get_include_path();' <enter>
.:/usr/local/lib/php%                      `

Comment: Well this is why you should use `include_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/autoload.php');`. Or use a config file where you create a constant with `realpath(dirname(__FILE__))` so you have control over this in your script and make sure your script will work in other environments where you have no control over PHP's config.

Comment: Searching in the cwd as a backstop seems more strange to me, given how php is normally used.

Comment: @icecub well it's turtles all the way down, how would you include that initial config file? And that's exactly how I ran into this. The `common.php` in my example *is* that config file. BTW, `dirname(__FILE__)` can be shortened with `__DIR__` right? That is what I was doing as a solution anyway.

Comment: Ye `__DIR__` should work fine. And you include the initial config by hard coding `__DIR__` in your script. I personally work with [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) so I have [PSR-4 autoloading](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGSerlMoIrY) available to me. So I don't have to worry about this.

Comment: @ChrisLear Do you want to answer this one or should I do it? I think this one is worth keeping for future readers.

Comment: Go ahead, if you think there's a valuable answer to this question

Comment: @icecub indeed we also use PSR-4 and Composer, but even then you need to refer to the (correct) autoloader.php at one point.

Comment: No you don't. Composer does that for you :) It's already in the default script

Comment: Then I'm not sure what the "default script" is. Even in your referenced youtube, their index.php still needs to include  the `autoloader.php`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake there. Answered it too quickly because I have a default script for it. The [basic guide](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md) tells you to use `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` which does what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the comments, the issue is that you've set your `include_path` in your php.ini file to a default setting. In your case `.`

This is why it's best to have a configuration file in your script(s) where you create a constant like this:

PHP >= 5.3.0

```
define("PATH", __DIR__);
```

PHP < 5.3.0

```
define("PATH", dirname(__FILE__));
```

This will give you control over which file you wish to include from the current working directory and will make sure your script will still work in a different environment where you may not have any control over PHP's configuration.

Comment: Your last paragraph is not really an alternative as discussed in the OP's comments. Please remove so I can accept this answer.

Comment: @hbogert Removed it. Though I do believe it would be good information for other users visiting this question in the future :)

Comment: That assumes that all include/require statements should always be done by something like composer or PSR-4. Which either is rather opinionated or simply does not apply.